# Tensorflow : logits and labels must have the same first dimension

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-datasets, tensorflow-estimator

I am new in tensoflow and I want to adapt the MNIST tutorial https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/layers with my own data (images of 40x40).
This is my model function :

```
def cnn_model_fn(features, labels, mode):
        # Input Layer
        input_layer = tf.reshape(features, [-1, 40, 40, 1])

        # Convolutional Layer #1
        conv1 = tf.layers.conv2d(
                inputs=input_layer,
                filters=32,
                kernel_size=[5, 5],
                #  To specify that the output tensor should have the same width and height values as the input tensor
                # value can be "same" ou "valid"
                padding="same",
                activation=tf.nn.relu)

        # Pooling Layer #1
        pool1 = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(inputs=conv1, pool_size=[2, 2], strides=2)

        # Convolutional Layer #2 and Pooling Layer #2
        conv2 = tf.layers.conv2d(
                inputs=pool1,
                filters=64,
                kernel_size=[5, 5],
                padding="same",
                activation=tf.nn.relu)
        pool2 = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(inputs=conv2, pool_size=[2, 2], strides=2)

        # Dense Layer
        pool2_flat = tf.reshape(pool2, [-1, 10 * 10 * 64])
        dense = tf.layers.dense(inputs=pool2_flat, units=1024, activation=tf.nn.relu)
        dropout = tf.layers.dropout(
                inputs=dense, rate=0.4, training=mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN)

        # Logits Layer
        logits = tf.layers.dense(inputs=dropout, units=2)

        predictions = {
            # Generate predictions (for PREDICT and EVAL mode)
            "classes":       tf.argmax(input=logits, axis=1),
            # Add `softmax_tensor` to the graph. It is used for PREDICT and by the
            # `logging_hook`.
            "probabilities": tf.nn.softmax(logits, name="softmax_tensor")
        }

        if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.PREDICT:
            return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode=mode, predictions=predictions)

        # Calculate Loss (for both TRAIN and EVAL modes)
        loss = tf.losses.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy(labels=labels, logits=logits)

        # Configure the Training Op (for TRAIN mode)
        if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN:
            optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=0.001)
            train_op = optimizer.minimize(
                    loss=loss,
                    global_step=tf.train.get_global_step())
            return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode=mode, loss=loss, train_op=train_op)

        # Add evaluation metrics (for EVAL mode)
        eval_metric_ops = {
            "accuracy": tf.metrics.accuracy(
                    labels=labels, predictions=predictions["classes"])}
        return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(
                mode=mode, loss=loss, eval_metric_ops=eval_metric_ops)
```

I have a shape size error between labels and logits :

**InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): logits and labels must have the same first dimension, got logits shape [3,2] and labels shape [1]**

filenames_array is an array of 16 string

```
["file1.png", "file2.png", "file3.png", ...]
```

and labels_array is an array of 16 integer

```
[0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,...]
```

The main function is :

```
# Create the Estimator
mnist_classifier = tf.estimator.Estimator(model_fn=cnn_model_fn, model_dir="/tmp/test_convnet_model")

# Train the model
cust_train_input_fn = lambda: train_input_fn_custom(
        filenames_array=filenames, labels_array=labels, batch_size=1)

mnist_classifier.train(
        input_fn=cust_train_input_fn,
        steps=20000,
        hooks=[logging_hook])
```

I tried to reshape logits without success :

logits = tf.reshape(logits, [1, 2])

I need your help, thanks

---

**EDIT**

After more time to search, in the first line of my model function

```
input_layer = tf.reshape(features, [-1, 40, 40, 1])
```

the "-1" that signifies that the batch_size dimension will be dynamically calculated have here the value "3". The same "3" as in my error : **logits and labels must have the same first dimension, got logits shape [3,2] and labels shape [1]**

If I force the value to "1" I have this new error :

**Input to reshape is a tensor with 4800 values, but the requested shape has 1600**

Maybe a problem with my features ?

---

**EDIT2 :**

the complete code is here : https://gist.github.com/geoffreyp/cc8e97aab1bff4d39e10001118c6322e

---

**EDIT3**

I updated the gist with

```
logits = tf.layers.dense(inputs=dropout, units=1)
```

https://gist.github.com/geoffreyp/cc8e97aab1bff4d39e10001118c6322e

But I don't completely understand your answer about the batch size, how the batch size can be 3 here whereas I choose a batch size of 1 ?

If I choose a batch_size = 3 I have this error :
**logits and labels must have the same first dimension, got logits shape [9,1] and labels shape [3]**

I tried to reshape labels :

```
labels = tf.reshape(labels, [3, 1])
```

and I updated features and labels structure :

```
    filenames_train = [['blackcorner-data/1.png', 'blackcorner-data/2.png', 'blackcorner-data/3.png',
                   'blackcorner-data/4.png', 'blackcorner-data/n1.png'],
                   ['blackcorner-data/n2.png',
                   'blackcorner-data/n3.png', 'blackcorner-data/n4.png',
                   'blackcorner-data/11.png', 'blackcorner-data/21.png'],
                   ['blackcorner-data/31.png',
                   'blackcorner-data/41.png', 'blackcorner-data/n11.png', 'blackcorner-data/n21.png',
                   'blackcorner-data/n31.png']
                   ]

labels = [[0, 0, 0, 0, 1], [1, 1, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 1, 1]]
```

but without success...

Answer (score 86, accepted):

The problem is in your target shape and is related to the correct choice of an appropriate loss function. you have 2 possibilities:

**1. possibility**: if you have 1D integer encoded target, you can use `sparse_categorical_crossentropy` as loss function

```
n_class = 3
n_features = 100
n_sample = 1000

X = np.random.randint(0,10, (n_sample,n_features))
y = np.random.randint(0,n_class, n_sample)

inp = Input((n_features,))
x = Dense(128, activation='relu')(inp)
out = Dense(n_class, activation='softmax')(x)

model = Model(inp, out)
model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',optimizer='adam',metrics=['accuracy'])
history = model.fit(X, y, epochs=3)
```

**2. possibility**: if you have one-hot encoded your target in order to have 2D shape (n_samples, n_class), you can use `categorical_crossentropy`

```
n_class = 3
n_features = 100
n_sample = 1000

X = np.random.randint(0,10, (n_sample,n_features))
y = pd.get_dummies(np.random.randint(0,n_class, n_sample)).values

inp = Input((n_features,))
x = Dense(128, activation='relu')(inp)
out = Dense(n_class, activation='softmax')(x)

model = Model(inp, out)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',optimizer='adam',metrics=['accuracy'])
history = model.fit(X, y, epochs=3)
```

Answer (score 52):

I resolved it changing from `sparse_categorical_crossentropy` to `categorical_crossentropy` and is now running fine.

Comment: This helped me. I also don't know why.

Comment: Here the explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49161174/tensorflow-logits-and-labels-must-have-the-same-first-dimension/62286888#62286888

Comment: This solved my problem too. Now, I need to understand why.

Answer (score 12):

I already had this problem in my first time using tensorflow, i figured out that my problem was forgetting to add the attribute `class_mode='sparse'` / `class_mode='binary'` to the function that uploads tha training data and validation data :

So try to look after the class_mode option

```
image_gen_val = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
val_data_gen = image_gen_val.flow_from_directory(batch_size=batch_size,
                                                 directory=val_dir,
                                                 target_size=(IMG_SHAPE, IMG_SHAPE),
                                                 class_mode='sparse')
```

Answer (score 9):

I thought I'd provide a more illustrative answer of the recommended methods for different label representations + some insights to what's happening.

First of all some context. We have 3 data points and 5 possible labels (0-indexed) Here are the different types of labels you'll encounter in ML problems.

[image]

### Code (`tensorflow2`)

Say we have the following dummy data and the model

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

ohe_labels = np.array([[0, 0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 1]])
labels = np.argmax(ohe_labels, axis=-1)

x = np.random.normal(size=(3, 10))

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential(
    [
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(20, 'relu', input_shape=(10,)),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(5, 'softmax')
    ]
)
```

```
# This works!

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam')
model.fit(x, ohe_labels)

# This also works!
model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam')
model.fit(x, labels)

# This does NOT (Different error - ValueError: Shapes ... are incompatible)!
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam')
model.fit(x, labels)

# This does NOT (Gives the above error)!
model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam')
model.fit(x, ohe_labels)
```

### When is this error triggered?

This error is triggered in a special condition. Let me explain with a problem that has a single label per input (explanation applies for multi label settings as well - but need few more added details). The first (batch) dimension needs to match but once `labels` is reshaped to a 1D vector, if the first dimension of `logits` and length of `labels` don't match, this error will be triggered.

Comment: this is a great explanation

Answer (score 3):

I have faced a similar issue and found out that I have missed the flatten layer between CNN and Dense layers. Adding the flatten layer resolved this issue for me.

Comment: There are some very good and detailed explanations here, but this is what solved for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your logits shape looks right, batch size of 3, and output layer of size 2, which is what you defined as your output layer. Your labels should be shape [3, 2] also. Batch of 3, and each batch has 2 [1,0] or [0,1].

Also note that when you have a boolean classification output you shouldn't have 2 neurons on the output/logits layer. You can just output a single value which takes on 0 or 1, you can probably see how 2 outputs of [1,0], and [0,1] is redundant and can be expressed as a simple [0|1] value. Also you tend to get better results when you do it this way.

Thus, your logits should end up being [3,1] and your labels should be an array of 3 values, one for each of the samples in your batch.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and it turned out that one pooling layer was not reshaped correctly. I was incorrectly using in my case `tf.reshape(pool, shape=[-1, 64 * 7 * 7])` instead of `tf.reshape(pool, shape=[-1, 64 * 14 * 14])`, which lead to a similar error massage about logits and labels. Altering the factors, e.g. `tf.reshape(pool, shape=[-1, 64 * 12 * 12])` lead to a completely different, less misleading error message.

Perhaps this is also the case here. I recommend going through the code checking the shapes of the nodes, just in case.