# Error while training a deep learning model

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0

So I designed a CNN and compiled with following parameters,

```
training_file_loc = "8-SignLanguageMNIST/sign_mnist_train.csv"
testing_file_loc = "8-SignLanguageMNIST/sign_mnist_test.csv"

def getData(filename):
    images = []
    labels = []
    with open(filename) as csv_file:
        file = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter = ",")
        next(file, None)
        
        for row in file:
            label = row[0]
            data = row[1:]
            img = np.array(data).reshape(28,28)
            
            images.append(img)
            labels.append(label)
        
        images = np.array(images).astype("float64")
        labels = np.array(labels).astype("float64")
        
    return images, labels

training_images, training_labels = getData(training_file_loc)
testing_images, testing_labels = getData(testing_file_loc)

print(training_images.shape, training_labels.shape)
print(testing_images.shape, testing_labels.shape)

training_images = np.expand_dims(training_images, axis = 3)
testing_images = np.expand_dims(testing_images, axis = 3)

training_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale = 1/255,
    rotation_range = 45,
    width_shift_range = 0.2,
    height_shift_range = 0.2,
    shear_range = 0.2,
    zoom_range = 0.2,
    horizontal_flip = True,
    fill_mode = "nearest"
)

training_generator = training_datagen.flow(
    training_images,
    training_labels,
    batch_size = 64,
)


validation_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale = 1/255,
    rotation_range = 45,
    width_shift_range = 0.2,
    height_shift_range = 0.2,
    shear_range = 0.2,
    zoom_range = 0.2,
    horizontal_flip = True,
    fill_mode = "nearest"
)

validation_generator = training_datagen.flow(
    testing_images,
    testing_labels,
    batch_size = 64,
)

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Conv2D(16, (3, 3), input_shape = (28, 28, 1), activation = "relu"),
    keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2, 2),
    keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation = "relu"),
    keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2, 2),
    keras.layers.Flatten(),
    keras.layers.Dense(256, activation = "relu"),
    keras.layers.Dropout(0.25),
    keras.layers.Dense(512, activation = "relu"),
    keras.layers.Dropout(0.25),
    keras.layers.Dense(26, activation = "softmax")
])

model.compile(
    loss = "categorical_crossentropy",
    optimizer = RMSprop(lr = 0.001),
    metrics = ["accuracy"]
)
```

But, as I ran the model.fit(), I get the following error,

```
ValueError: Shapes (None, 1) and (None, 24) are incompatible
```

After changing the loss function to `sparse_categorical_crossentropy`, program worked fine.

I don't understand why this happened.

Can anyone explain this and also the difference between those loss functions?

Comment: here the explanation of the differences between those losses: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49161174/tensorflow-logits-and-labels-must-have-the-same-first-dimension/62286888#62286888

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is, `categorical_crossentropy` expects one-hot-encoded labels, which means, for each sample it expects a tensor of length `num_classes` where the `label`th element is set to 1 and everything else is 0.

On the other hand, `sparse_categorical_crossentropy` uses integer labels directly (because the use-case here is a big number of classes, so the one-hot-encoded label would waste memory with a lot of zeros). I believe, but I can't confirm this, that `categorical_crossentropy` is faster to run than its sparse counterpart.

For your case, with 26 classes I'd recommend using the non-sparse version and transform your labels to be one-hot encoded like so:

```py
def getData(filename):
    images = []
    labels = []
    with open(filename) as csv_file:
        file = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter = ",")
        next(file, None)
        
        for row in file:
            label = row[0]
            data = row[1:]
            img = np.array(data).reshape(28,28)
            
            images.append(img)
            labels.append(label)
        
        images = np.array(images).astype("float64")
        labels = np.array(labels).astype("float64")
        
    return images, tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(labels, num_classes=26) # you can omit num_classes to have it computed from the data
```

---

Side note: unless you have a reason to use `float64` for images, I'd switch to `float32` (it halves the memory required for the dataset and the model likely converts them to `float32` as the first operation anyway)

Comment: One more question, as you said it is better to use labels instead of one-hot-encoding because of memory. So when I use "flow_from_directory" to generate labels for image, so does that generate one-hot-encoded labels?

Comment: I actually said the opposite: Prefer one-hot-encoded unless you have memory issues.  flow_from_directory returns the labels according to the class_mode argument (have a look at the docs for all possible values)

Answer (score 0):

Simple, For the classification problem where your output classes are in integers sparse_categorical_crosentropy, is used and for those where the labels are converted in one hot encoded labels, we use categorical_crosentropy.