# Keras model predict and sklearn confusion matrix results issue

Tags: tensorflow, tf.keras

I'm having issues with a Keras model, with the predictions and confusion matrix.

I want to change this Keras tutorial for multiple classes.

https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/structured_data/feature_columns

I read in data and encode the 6 `string` target classes to `int`

```
dataframe = pd.read_csv("my_csv.csv")
target = 'some_target'
labelencoder = LabelEncoder()
dataframe[target] = labelencoder.fit_transform(dataframe[target])
```

Then I split data, create columns, create model and fit

```
train, test = train_test_split(dataframe, test_size=0.2)
train, val = train_test_split(train, test_size=0.2)


# A utility method to create a tf.data dataset from a Pandas Dataframe
def df_to_dataset(dataframe, target, shuffle=True, batch_size=32):
    dataframe = dataframe.copy()
    labels = dataframe.pop(target)
    ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((dict(dataframe), labels))
    if shuffle:
        ds = ds.shuffle(buffer_size=len(dataframe))
    ds = ds.batch(batch_size)
    return ds, labels

feature_columns = []
 
f = feature_column.categorical_column_with_vocabulary_list(
    field, unique_categories)
feature_columns.append(feature_column.embedding_column(f, dimension=8))

f2 = feature_column.categorical_column_with_vocabulary_list(
    field, unique_categories)
indicator_column = feature_column.indicator_column(f2)
feature_columns.append(indicator_column)

feature_columns.append(feature_column.numeric_column(field))

feature_layer = tf.keras.layers.DenseFeatures(feature_columns)

batch_size = 32
train_ds, train_labels = df_to_dataset(train, target, batch_size=batch_size)
val_ds, val_labels = df_to_dataset(val, target, shuffle=False, batch_size=batch_size)
test_ds, test_labels = df_to_dataset(test, target, shuffle=False, batch_size=batch_size)

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    feature_layer,
    layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
    layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
    layers.Dropout(.1),
    layers.Dense(1, activation='softmax')
])


# get hps
optimizer = 'adam'
loss_function = tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True)
metrics = ['accuracy']
epochs = 1

model.compile(optimizer=optimizer,
              loss=loss_function,
              metrics=metrics)

model.fit(train_ds,
          validation_data=val_ds,
          epochs=epochs)

loss, accuracy = model.evaluate(test_ds)
print("Accuracy", accuracy)

predicted = model.predict(test_ds)

cf = confusion_matrix(test_labels, predicted)
```

When I run model.predict the output is strange

```
[1.]
[1.]
[1.]
[1.]
[1.]
[1.]
[1.]
[1.]
```

And the confusion matrix is also not correct

```
[ 0 33  0  0  0  0]
[  0 499   0   0   0   0]
[ 0 14  0  0  0  0]
[   0 1089    0    0    0    0]
[  0 360   0   0   0   0]
[0 4 0 0 0 0]
```

I have tried different encoding for target, changing loss but to no avail

```
# mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()
# dataframe[target] = mlb.fit_transform(dataframe[target])

loss='categorical_crossentropy'
```

What am I doing wrong here ?

Also tried with 6 output neurons

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    feature_layer,
    layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
    layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
    layers.Dropout(.1),
    layers.Dense(6, activation='softmax')
])
```

but got error

```
ValueError: logits and labels must have the same shape ((None, 6) vs (None, 1))
```

EDIT:

```
print(type(train_ds))
# <class 'tensorflow.python.data.ops.dataset_ops.BatchDataset'>

print(train_ds)
# <BatchDataset shapes: ({feature1: (None,), feature2: (None,), feature3: (None,), feature4: (None,) ...

print(type(train_labels))
# <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

EDIT:
Making a bit of progress. Turns out the loss function and target dim are dependent:
[Tensorflow : logits and labels must have the same first dimension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49161174/tensorflow-logits-and-labels-must-have-the-same-first-dimension)

*if you have 1D integer encoded target, you can use sparse_categorical_crossentropy as loss function*

So changed loss to:
`sparse_categorical_crossentropy`

Now when I run model.predict the output looks better

```
[0.02313532 0.39231667 0.0117254  0.42083895 0.15037686 0.00160678]
[2.3085043e-02 3.3588389e-01 8.1730038e-03 4.8321337e-01 1.4923279e-01
 4.1199493e-04]
[8.1658429e-03 3.3901721e-01 2.3666199e-03 5.3861737e-01 1.1167890e-01
 1.5400720e-04]
[8.6198252e-04 1.2048376e-01 1.3487167e-02 4.1729528e-01 4.4759643e-01
 2.7547608e-04]
[0.06842247 0.31534496 0.02852604 0.40057638 0.17933881 0.0077913 ]
[0.05149424 0.34782204 0.02664029 0.34621894 0.22060096 0.00722347]
```

Then get the index of highest prediction and pass into confusion matrix

```
predictions_index = np.argmax(predicted, axis=1)
cf = confusion_matrix(test_labels, predictions_index)
```

And confusion matrix looks better

```
[ 0  3  0 27  2  0]
[  0  37   0 386  54   0]
[ 0  0  0 14  1  0]
[  0  13   0 968 124   0]
[  0   4   0 309  49   0]
[0 0 0 6 2 0]
```

Comment: You did not change the number of neurons of the last layer of your model, it should be equial to the number of classes

Comment: I had tried with 6 output neurons but got error - ValueError: logits and labels must have the same shape ((None, 6) vs (None, 1))

Comment: What are the shapes of the train_ds and train_labels?

Comment: @yuRa - updated for shape and type